# How to Trim a General Tree of Tic Tac Toe Boards - Java Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tree, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make each parent node (every node) show me a how many wins and losses its subtree has.

This will allow me to play a computer such that the computer can optimize its move by going to the next subtree that has the most wins for O.

Right now I am trying to rearrange the tree so that it can simply show me how many wins and losses its subtree has.

So far I have a tree that is ordered such that there is 9 generations.

1) The first generation has 8 siblings (each with children nodes) or 8 possible Moves for X.

2) The second generation has 7 siblings (each with children nodes) or 7 possible Moves for O.

3) Continues until the last generation has zero siblings and a full board.

4) I have 986410 possible (complete and incomplete) boards.

This method currently prints the number of all possible wins (for both X and O) in the whole tree. However it doubles the amount of tree nodes, when it should be less then the original amount because not all nodes are wins.

```
public void postOrderTraverse(TreeNode T) {

        counter++;

        if (T == null) {
            return;
        } else {

            postOrderTraverse(T.firstChild);
            postOrderTraverse(T.nextSibling);

            // checks diagonals, horizontals and verticals for a set of X's or O's
                if (winOrProgress(T.board, X) == true || winOrProgress(T.board, O) == true) {

                    // prints the game board at this node
                    char[][] gameBoard = T.board;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            char value = gameBoard[i][j];
                            System.out.print(value);
                        }
                    }
                    T.firstChild = T;
                    System.out.print(counter);
                    System.out.println("Win");
                }

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put counter right after the call which will count all nodes even null ones.
change it to be inside the else statement.  but that is only part of you problem.  This will correctly count all nodes not just winners.  if you want to count only the winning nodes you need to put it in that catch and not the else.

```
public void postOrderTraverse(TreeNode T) {


    if (T == null) {
        return;
    } else {
         counter++;  //this is where you need to put counter, not before the actual call that way you are not counting null nodes. which you would be adding at most 2 nodes for every node that doesn't have any children.


        postOrderTraverse(T.firstChild);
        postOrderTraverse(T.nextSibling);
```

Comment: but from your code you are not properly checking to see if you have a winner or I am not reading your loops correctly as you do not have a sentinel value you flag for the win.